# Get an error cursor.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect to our internal mongodb cloud DB. I am getting an error cursor.map is not a function. How to solve this problem and I'm not able to find what is causing this error.

````
const dbConnectionUrl = `mongodb://${user}:${encodeURIComponent(pwd)}@0000000000.dev.cloud.company.net:27017/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;



   const arr = [];
    MongoClient.connect(dbConnectionUrl, {
            useNewUrlParser: true, 
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        },function(err, client){
            assert.equal(null, err);
            const cursor = client.db('tss-db').collection('jenkins-inventory').find({"instance" : "build01"}).toArray();
            cursor.map(function(instances, err){
                assert.equal(null, err);
                    arr.push(instances);
                    console.log(instances)
                }, 
                function(){
                    client.close()
            res.render('L2');        
        });
    });```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`toArray`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Cursor.html#toArray) does not return an array. `toArray` involves pulling all the objects out of the Cursor, which can take a long time and is therefore done asynchronously .

`toArray` takes a callback and returns a `then`-able Promise, either of which can be used to execute a function after the Cursor has had all its objects put into an array:

```
someCursor.toArray(function(resultingArray) {
    // do something with resultingArray
});
```

or

```
someCursor.toArray().then(function(resultingArray) {
    // do something with resultingArray
});
```

Note that either option will run chronologically after the Cursor is emptied out, which could take a long time. In the mean time, other code may run; see [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Also you code is a little hard to read, and does something that doesn't make sense to me:

- The indentation around the `map` is confusing
- You pass a second function argument into `map` (you do `cursor.map(function() { ... }, function() { ... }`) which doesn't do anything meaningful
- if the only meaningful thing you do in `.map` is add elements to another array, you can use the result of the `map` directly instead: `arr = cursor.map(...)` (or if you want to be selective, use `filter`).

Comment: Solved!, Thank You @apsillers